# SQL adding two columns and group by count

Tags: sql, intersystems-cache

I want to add two columns and group by the count.
For example say I have the following table:

```
ID -------- value1 ---------- value2    
A ------------ 2 -----------------3    
B ------------ 1 -----------------4    
c ------------ 2 -----------------2   
D ------------ 3 -----------------3   
E ------------ 2 -----------------1
F ------------ 1 -----------------3
```

Ff you count the sum `(select value1 + value 2)` in each rows you will get 5,5,4,6,3,4.

I would like to get the following result.

```
5 ------ 2    
4 ------ 2   
3 ------ 1   
6 ------ 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just do:

```
select (val1 + val2), count(*)
from t
group by (val1 + val2)
order by count(*) desc;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one solution: make the `SUM` of the two columns in `CTE` and then just `COUNT` the id's grouped by the sum amount:

```
declare @tbl as table (
    id varchar(1)
    ,val1 int
    ,val2 int
)

insert into @tbl values ('A',2,3)
insert into @tbl values ('B',1,4)
insert into @tbl values ('C',2,2)
insert into @tbl values ('D',3,3)
insert into @tbl values ('E',2,1)
insert into @tbl values ('F',1,3)

;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT
        id
        ,val1+val2 as [sum]
    FROM @tbl
)
SELECT
    [sum]
    ,count(id) as [count]
FROM CTE
GROUP BY sum
```